# Get a list of the last posts grouped by author and filtered by category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i need a list of the latest post published by various authors, but filtered by category, like for example the latest posts of author that write about music.

i wrote this query and looks like working in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN 
        wp_term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE 
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 7
        AND
        $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'

    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
)
AS x GROUP BY post_author
```

*(the 7 is just an example category id)*

i just would like to know the other `$wpdb` functions to call the `wp_term_relationships` table and if is there something wrong with this query

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => $category_id,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thank you for answering but that's not the point, i need the last post by *each* author filtered by category